# Pipeline alterar variável de ambiente

Tags: gitlab, integração-contínua

Tenho uma variável ambiente de *nível de projeto* definida com o valor `X`.

Durante a execução do pipeline, dada uma determinada condição, preciso alterar o valor dessa variável para `Y`.
O valor precisa ser *persistido* na variável para que na próxima execução o pipeline use o valor `Y` e não o `X`.

É possível?
Se sim, como?

---

Obs: não vou postar o código do meu `.gitlab-ci.yml` pois não consegui evoluir nada em relação a esse assunto, dessa forma não agregaria na pergunta.

Comment: Do jeito como foi disposto aqui, não consigo pensar em método não gambioso de se fazer isso. Não estudei a API do GitLab a fundo para de repente fazer uma chamada CURL e mandar um novo valor

Comment: Outras alternativas que enxergo são todas envolvendo repositórios externos, como um banco na nuvem ou uma aplicação sua que recebe a requisição. Nem mesmo por em cache adiantar-lhe-á, pois o cache do gitlab é bem caótico

Comment: Não sei se foi a sua ideia, mas o seu primeiro comentário me fez pensar em consumir a API REST deles.. (Aparentemente dá pra fazer)[https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable], mas fica um pouco estranho.. O pipeline tá sendo executado naquele ambiente, ao invés de fazer um `export` ou algo do tipo precisarei fazer uma requisição HTTP pra fazer esse trabalho :P Mas... aparenta ser a solução menos _estranha_ @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: o `export` não é uma alternativa boa, porque na realidade ele só permite que processos filhos novos enxerguem a variável de ambiente. Ele não afeta antepassados, filhos velhos ou "primos" (como são todos filhos do PID 1, se não for descendente nem ancestral, então é primo). E o pipeline, no meu entender, não é executado no mesmo ambiente, principalmente quando o runner se comunica com um docker para subir as imagens. Então, cada execução (cada job distinto de cada pipeline distinto, até mesmo entre duas execuções distintas do mesmo job no mesmo pipeline) é feita num amb novo